# A doubt in Ramanujan's proof of Chebycheff's Theorem in number theory

Tags: number-theory, self-learning, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory, chebyshev-function

I am self studying analytic number theory from An introduction to Sieve Methods  and its applications by Alina Carmen and M Ram Murthy .

I have a doubt on page 7 in Theorem  of chebyscheff  whose proof was given by S. Ramanujan .

> Authors defines $\psi(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n) $ and then $T(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} \psi(x/n) $.
>
> Then Authors after some steps just writes without giving any argument $T(x) - 2T(x/2) = \sum_{n\leq x} (-1)^{n-1} \psi(x/n) $.

I don't understand how authors derive it and I could not think about it despite trying many times. Can someone please tell how to derive it?

Comment: If this happens to you again, you should simply to do the math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given that

$$ T(x) := \psi(x) + \psi\Big(\frac{x}2\Big) +
 \psi\Big(\frac{x}3\Big) + \psi\Big(\frac{x}4\Big) + \dots $$

and thus

$$ T\Big(\frac{x}2\Big) = \psi\Big(\frac{x}2\Big) + 
\psi\Big(\frac{x}4\Big) + \psi\Big(\frac{x}6\Big) +\dots. $$

Subtract twice the second equation from the first to get

$$ T(x) \!-\! 2\,T\Big(\frac{x}2\Big) = \psi(x)\!-\!
\psi\Big(\frac{x}2\Big) \!+\! \psi\Big(\frac{x}3\Big) - \psi\Big(\frac{x}4\Big) \!+\! \dots  $$

where we have just changed the signs of
every term with $\,n\,$ even but all of
the terms with $\,n\,$ odd are not changed because the
$\,T(\frac{x}2)\,$ summation only includes
terms with $\,n\,$ even.